# How to check the node/vertex/Edge is present in the Graph using Gremlin

Tags: database, graph, gremlin

How to check the `node/vertex` or `edge` is present in the `Graph` using the `Gremlin` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the node/Vertex

```
   //Returns True or False
   g.V('id').hasNext()
```

To check the edge

```
 //Returns True or False
 g.V('id).bothE().hasNext();
```